# Description under nodes-teasers

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

How to display description of taxonomy term under the node-teasers associated with this term?

there is a taxonomy-term.tpl.php template, but content of this template is displyed above the nodes teasers so description will appear before list of nodes. I need to display it at bottom, after list of nodes and pager line.

List of nodes is rendering after this template. So I need another way to display it

Answer (score 1):

You need to pluck the `description` element from the `content` array and render it separately on the page. Change `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` to look something like this:

```
<?php 
$description = render($content['description']); 
hide($content['description']);
?>

<div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php print $term_url; ?>"><?php print $term_name; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content">
    <?php print render($content); ?>

    <?php print $description; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Clive, but description will appear before list of nodes. I need to display it at bottom, after list of nodes and pager line. List of nodes is rendering after this template. So I need another way to display it.